# Split dataframe column into 2 by the last special character

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, split

I have the following dataframe, and would like to split the name column by the last underscore "_"  and assign the last 4 values to a "Date" column.  But get an indexing error.  How do I accomplish this?

```
name           val
NETUSE_2014     1
NETUSE_2015     1
NETUSE_2016     1
NETUSE_2017     1
NET_ALL_2013    1
NET_ALL_2014    1
NET_ALL_2015    1
NET_ALL_2016    1

df['Year'] = df['name'].str[-4:]
```

I get this error:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  wet2['date'] = wet2['name'].str[-4:]
```

I would like the following dataframe:

```
name    val date
NETUSE  1   2014
NETUSE  1   2015
NETUSE  1   2016
NETUSE  1   2017
NET_ALL 1   2013
NET_ALL 1   2014
NET_ALL 1   2015
NET_ALL 1   2016
```

Comment: the warning comes from how you create `wet2` I think. is it a part of a bigger dataframe? how do you create it?

Comment: Do upvote if you find it helpful

Answer (score 2):

simply do this !!works!!

```
df['date'] = df['name'].str[-4:]
df['name'] = df['name'].str[:-5]
```

output:

```
      name  val  year
0   NETUSE    1  2014
1   NETUSE    1  2015
2   NETUSE    1  2016
3   NETUSE    1  2017
4  NET_ALL    1  2013
5  NET_ALL    1  2014
6  NET_ALL    1  2015
7  NET_ALL    1  2016
```

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try
> using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

this error occurs when we try to assign value using filter or to a sliced dataframe. using the code mentioned above error doesn't occur